# How to get Google CloudSQL Instance up and running

Tags: wordpress, google-cloud-sql

I am working deploying Wordpress to Google App Engine and I believe I am almost there. The biggest issue is that the Google CloudSQL instance I created is always listed as "Runnable" and I cannot seem to get it up and "Running". I am able to restart the instance and do not receive any errors however the status is always listed as "Runnable".

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you can connect to the instance using mysql cli, then the instance is already running.

https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/docs/mysql-client#connect

Answer (score 0):

An instance can be either active or dormant with the "Runnable" status. "Runnable" only means that the instance can spin up (as opposed to being suspended or going under maintenance). There is no "Running" status.

Unfortunately we don't have a clear indication in the UI to show whether the instance is currently active. You can use the monitoring graph as a proxy. If there are disk read/write operations, the instance is up.